# Valgrind finding memory leak for string even after I free it

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

In my program I declare some nodes in a linked list:

```
node_t* newSymbol = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

newSymbol->symbol.name = strdup(name); //name is a (const) char* that is a parameter to function I'm in.
newSymbol->symbol.addr = addr;
```

I use strdup because assigning the symbols name to the parameter directly like this:

```
newSymbol->symbol.name = name;
```

says there is an error when I discard the const property of the passed param.

***Issue***: I read on another stack overflow that you need to free memory created by strdup. I do the following for each node as my program exits:

```
free((void*)node->symbol.name);//free the memory allocated by strdup
free((void*)node);//here I free the node itself
```

I've managed to clear all leak issues except one:

```
8 bytes in 1 blocks are definetely lost in loss record 1 of 1
    at 0x4C2DB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
    by 0x4ECE489: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so)
    by 0x400EE7: symbol_add (symbol.c:117)
```

I checked line 117 of symbol.c and sure enough it's where strdup is used as I have pasted above. I'm not sure how to clear the memory associated with this so I don't get any memory leaks. Please Help! Thanks so much.

Comment: Valgrind explicitly says the memory block is lost by strdup at line 117 of symbol.c. That line is `newSymbol->symbol.name = strdup(name);` I free this later with `free((void*)node->symbol.name);` Should I look somewhere else for leaks?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but memory gets freed automatically when the program exits.  Freeing just before the program exits doesn't really net you anything in practice.  The benefits come from bigger programs where you are allocating a lot of memory on the heap that is not intended to last for the entire life of the program.

Comment: maybe that's because `newSymbol->symbol.name ` was allocated

Comment: Yes, so that would mean that `newSymbol->symbol.name` was already pointing to a `malloc`ed block. Like I said, post the code of the function or a [mcve]

Comment: I think I was wrong in my comment. valgrind tracks the lost memory, which was allocated within strdup, not overwritten by the result of strdup. That would be too smart!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons for simple trivial programs that may be true, but you should learn how to free memory anyway. That's why beginners should always free the memory even for trivial small programs, so that they learn to do it and when they work in a bigger project, they don't write that leak like a broken water pipe.

Comment: btw `free((void*)node->symbol.name);` => `free(node->symbol.name);`

Comment: @Pablo Sorry, my intention was not to imply that OP shouldn't bother with freeing memory, but rather the best use is not to free memory "at the end of the program" and instead free the memory when your program is no longer in need of it.

Comment: The code shown is correct (although no need to cast the argument of free()). Therefore, the error is in the code you have not shown us.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ok, I misinterpreted your comment, sorry.

Comment: @Pablo, No, it was good to point it out.  I was already re-reading it and thinking it could have been more clear on that point.

Comment: @Pablo added code

Comment: Do you ever change the name field after you've added a symbol?

Comment: The code looks OK, I have a few issues with some of the lines (for example I don't understand why you use a double pointer `node_t **headNode;`) but they do not matter in this case. The error might be that at some point later (perhaps `symbol_search`) you overwrite `symbol.name` when looping on `symTable` with a new pointer. From the code you've shown us, it's not possible to see where the error is, because I think that the error is in another function.

Comment: I know this would mean a lot of work, but if you could create a [mcve] from your code that has the same behaviour, we could see where the problem is.

Comment: I recreated an example on my machine `char *ptr = strdup("Hello");ptr = strdup("world");free(ptr);` and valgrind shows me the exact same error and it tells where the "lost" pointer was created. So the error is not in the add function, it's somewhere else where you overwrite `symbol.name`

Comment: @Pablo thanks for all the help. My professors don't want us posting large chunks of source code online. I should be able to figure this out with the information in your last post.

Comment: Well, good look with that. I presume that another function is reassigning the names when iterating over the whole symbol table. You could use a debugger and run it step by step to see where the wrong assignment happen. I'm afraid that without more code, we would be only guessing.

Comment: Do you ever set `node->symbol.name` to null after it has been allocated.  Calling `free()` with a null pointer won't do any damage, but overwriting the pointer could easily leak the memory it was pointing at.  Do you have a mechanism for printing all the symbols?  How many symbols are you processing when you leak this one?

Comment: Are you sure you freed *all* of the strings allocated on that line? Perhaps it runs 100 times and you only free 95 of the strings?

Comment: Posting an MCVE doesn't imply you post "large chunks of code". It implies you pull out sufficient code, make it compilable and still exhibit the behavior of interest.  Often the exercise surfaces the root of the problem and you won't need our help.

Answer (score 0):

since the code snippet seems to be correct the basic assumption should be that you are `strdup` to an already allocatd pointer

to fix this, I would add:

```
/* free memory if it is already allocated */
if ( newSymbol->symbol.name ) 
    free( newSymbol->symbol.name);
newSymbol->symbol.name = strdup(name); //name is a (const) char* that is a parameter to function I'm in.
newSymbol->symbol.addr = addr;
```

Though it is importent to mention that even if it solves the issue, I would recommend continuing to debug your code as it seems that you are not actually freeing the memory correctly

hope that helps...

Comment: If you do this, ensure that the name field is initialized to NULL when it is created.